# Calculating primes until a user-given value

Tags: c#, beginner, primes

I am new to C# programming. I wrote a little program in C# to calculate all primes until a user-given value. Ignoring the lack of computing power I wrote this program to handle theoretically very huge numbers.

The code works properly. I have no error handling simply because it is a little program for myself. But I'd like some suggestions about error handling. :)

Can you give me suggestions to improve the code? Maybe even to make it faster?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsolePrimes
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Up to which number shall all primes be calculated?");
            string inputvar = Console.ReadLine();
            ulong inputnumber = Convert.ToUInt64(inputvar);
            var primes = new List<ulong>();
            primes.Add(2);
            primes.Add(3);
            bool isprime = false;
            double result = 0;
            for (ulong i = 4; i<inputnumber; i++)
            {
                isprime = true;
                foreach (ulong prime in primes)
                {
                    result = i % prime;
                    if (result == 0)
                    {
                        isprime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isprime == true)
                {
                    primes.Add(i);
                }
            }
            int numberofprimes = primes.Count;
            Console.WriteLine("The Range from 0 to " + inputvar + " has " + Convert.ToString(numberofprimes) + " primes.");
            Console.WriteLine("The list of all primes is now getting exported to \"primes.txt\".");
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("primes.txt");
            foreach (ulong nr in primes)
            {
               tw.WriteLine(nr);
            }
            tw.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at other C# programs that also involve prime numbers, e.g. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26272/prime-numbers-store , https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122756/lazy-prime-number-generator , https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40673/what-is-the-10001st-prime-number , https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/53840/prime-number-speed , https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143740/calculate-prime-numbers , https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196592/prime-numbers-generator , etc.

Comment: What happens for input less than 5?

Comment: You say in other comments `this brings us to 25999,5974ms for the calculation of the first 1.000.000 primes`.  Your code does not reflect that statement.  It does not find the first 1 million primes.  Rather it finds all the primes up to 1 million.  Using a sieve would take less than 6ms running in 64 bit Release mode.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Thanks for the tip. I will add an answer now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So this is a curious writeup, because primes can be calculated in many, many ways.

That said, there's one huge optimization we can use to cut your search pattern in half, and it starts here:

> ```
> for (ulong i = 4; i<inputnumber; i++)
> {
> ```

Fun fact: the **only** prime even number is `2`, so we can actually rewrite this very quickly to remove half of the numbers you need to search:

```
for (ulong i = 5; i<inputnumber; i += 2)
{
```

Bam. Cut our search grid in half.

The next thing I would do is remove `2` from the `List<ulong>` of results, and we'll insert it later, because that will *never* match any of the values we're searching now:

```
var primes = new List<ulong>();
primes.Add(3);
...
primes.Insert(0, 2);
```

That way we get another speed boost, without sacrificing any of the rest of our code. (Are there better ways to do this? Sure.)

---

Next, we need to talk about some "best practices" and such:

```
Console.WriteLine("The Range from 0 to " + inputvar + " has " + Convert.ToString(numberofprimes) + " primes.");
```

This is something we call "string concatenation", basically, `string1 + string2`. It's frowned upon, and we recommend not doing it. Instead, use a formatted string, in one of two ways:

```
Console.WriteLine("The Range from 0 to {0} has {1} primes.", inputvar, numberofprimes);
Console.WriteLine($"The Range from 0 to {inputvar} has {numberofprimes} primes.");
```

Either will work, though the second is only supported in C# 6.0.

---

Next, there's one more **huge** optimization to make, and it's at this line:

```
double result = 0;
```

You don't realize it, but there's a boatload of casting/conversions here that shouldn't exist. Replace `double` with `ulong` and it goes away.

What's happening, is `i % prime` is a `ulong`, that is being casted to a `double` when assigned to `result`. This is an expensive operation, because the two types are stored in memory in completely different formats. Change the type, and you should get a 50%+ speed boost. (At least, I did.)

---

Additionally, you don't really *need* `result`, you don't use it for anything. So, I recommend removing it, and rewriting the `foreach` as follows:

```
for (ulong i = 5; i < inputnumber; i += 2)
{
    isprime = true;
    foreach (ulong prime in primes)
    {
        if (i % prime == 0UL)
        {
            isprime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isprime == true)
    {
        primes.Add(i);
    }
}
```

This gives you another speed boost, surprisingly.

---

Lastly, I recommend initializing the `List` with a default buffer. This should help avoid "resizing" that happens throughout the lifetime of the program. I used 500000, but as long as you use something reasonable (even 10000 is fine) it will give you a decent performance boost. (1-2%)

---

Overall, when we're done, the algorithm should look something like:

```
var primes = new List<ulong>(10000);
primes.Add(3);
bool isprime = false;
for (ulong i = 5; i < inputnumber; i += 2)
{
    isprime = true;
    foreach (ulong prime in primes)
    {
        if (i % prime == 0UL)
        {
            isprime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isprime == true)
    {
        primes.Add(i);
    }
}
primes.Insert(0, 2);
int numberofprimes = primes.Count;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have tested it and actually it makes not much difference. In low numbers the new codes runs slower, in higher numbers (I tested 'til 1.000.000) it is a little faster (28146,8476ms compared to 28282,2768ms). Test it yourself if you don't believe me. ^^

Comment: That sounds reasonable. You'll want to remember that _most_ numbers are not prime, so you'll be iterating the entire `primes` list on almost every number, except those that are prime. (This is why prime calculation algorithms are notoriously slow.)

Comment: @Kajkrow I recommend reading the latest edit, there's a huge speed boost at the third section. ;)

Comment: this brings us to 25999,5974ms for the calculation of the first 1.000.000 primes. so we are talking about 2 seconds here. that's great. :) But I have no 50%+.

Comment: @Kajkrow Odd, mine dropped over 50%. What are you timing? I'm only timing the algorithm (at the very bottom).

Comment: I even copied what you provided me and still i have around the same duration. But i noticed something: I calculated 5 times in a row until 50000 and 2 of those 5 times I got around 120ms, the other 3 time sI have around 150ms. This is a pretty big difference...

Comment: But still THANK YOU that you take the time to help me! :)

Comment: @Kajkrow Interesting. As a final note: don't test in Visual Studio, run the test outside of it, in Release mode. You might see more differences.

Comment: Removing that `double` almost doubled the speed for me as well (pun intended). But a more significant improvement is to only check against primes up to the square root of `i`.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Aye, you should make that a new answer. ;)

Comment: @202_accepted I'm sry. I wrote that wrong. Not for the first 1.000.000 primes, but for all primes until 1.000.000. Surely, the drop becomes bigger and bigger as the amount of primes rise. And also I don't test inside VS. I use SharpDevelop and compile the code via a selfwritten batch bc the cs-compiler is in each windows. I do the same with VB. :) I wrote the code at work and there I am no admin.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem statement is to find all primes up to a given input number.  This just screams for a sieve-based solution.  Now IF your problem statement was something like [Project Euler Project 7](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7), which is to find the 10001st prime number, then a prime generator similar to what you've posted would be the better fit.

A couple of things to keep in mind, particularly since you are new to C#.  You need to find the right sized data type.  UInt64 covers really big numbers.  The problem is your solution required a List, which will cause memory issues before you get too far into the UInt32 numbers.

A more practical solution would be to scale your needs down to Int32 first.  This not only uses less memory, but will be faster.  Once you are happy there, then maybe step up to UInt32 and see how that goes.

I have already done such things with sieves from a hobbyist perspective.  You are free to look at it to pick up any ideas.

[Sieve31](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92366/sieve31-my-sieve-of-eratosthenes-returning-ienumerableint?rq=1)

[Sieve32FastV2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104736/sieve32fastv2-a-fast-parallel-sieve-of-eratosthenes)

Both of the above do not return a List, but rather an IEnumerable.  It does keep a compressed internal list in memory, but not of numbers themselves but rather of bits associated with a numeric index.  Besides memory concerns, keep in mind an array is limited to int.MaxValue items.

**Other Code Comments**

In addition to what @202_accepted wrote, I add:

You mix and match **var** and explicit type declarations.  Actually, you only use **var** once.  I'd suggest for consistency, you stick to one style.

You may simplify `(isprime == true)` to be `(isprime)`.

A little whitespace for `i<inputnumber` becomes easier with `i < inputnumber`.

As your C# skills improve, you may find yourself breaking your app up into more modular pieces.  Rather than having everything in Main(), you may find a cleaner organization of the code by having it: (1) perform data inputs and validation, (2) run primary method (i.e. generate list of primes), and finally (3) output to console and/or text file.

Answer (score 5):

> Maybe even to make it faster?

you don't need to do:

```
result % prime
```

for every prime in your list, it's enough to check every prime that is smaller then the square root of the number you're checking. So you can rewrite your code like this (eliminating useless conversions, as @202_accepted suggests, on the fly):

```
        for (ulong i = 4; i < inputnumber; i++)
        {
            isprime = true;
            ulong upperLimit = (ulong)(Math.Sqrt(i));

            foreach (ulong prime in primes)
            {
                if (prime > upperLimit)
                    break;

                if (i % prime == 0)
                {
                    isprime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isprime == true)
            {
                primes.Add(i);
            }
        }
```

It works because every number `n` that is not prime fulfills one of the following:

- it is a square number, in that case `sqrt(n)` is an integral value and gets checked by the code
- it is a product of more then one prime. In this case, there is either a prime factor larger than `sqrt(n)` or it is not. If there is none, we're done. If there is one, there must also be one smaller then `sqrt(n)`, otherwise `n` would be larger then itself, and we would've found that one by now.

This should give you a nice speed increase. On my machine, the Code went from "I'm to bored to wait" to about 300ms (for the primes <1000000).

For more speed you could just use int instead of ulong. Finding all primes for values larger then `int.MaxValue` is something you'll not see happening with that algorithm on a normal PC, unless you want to wait for ages.

Answer (score 0):

After lots and lots of input (Thank you all!) I created this solution now.
This is a improved code, that has a different approach to the problem. This code is limited to the first 2.000.000 numbers:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsolePrimes
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static bool[] nonprimes = new bool[2000001];
        public static ulong i = 2;
        public static ulong inputnumber = 0;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool repeat = true;
            while (repeat)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                //Console.WriteLine("Up to which number shall all primes be calculated?");
                Console.WriteLine("Calculation until 2.000.000...");
                //string inputvar = Console.ReadLine();
                string inputvar = "2000000";
                Console.ReadLine();
                Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                //inputnumber = Convert.ToUInt64(inputvar);
                inputnumber = 2000000;
                nonprimes[0] = true;
                nonprimes[1] = true;
                calcprime();
                i++;
                while ( i < inputnumber )
                {
                    calcprime();
                    i += 2;
                }
                List<ulong> primeoutput = new List<ulong>(1000000);
                ulong counter = 0;
                foreach (bool element in nonprimes)
                {
                    if (!(element))
                    {
                        primeoutput.Add(counter);
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                stopWatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("The Range from 0 to " + inputvar + " has " + Convert.ToString(primeoutput.Count) + " primes.");
                Console.WriteLine("The calculation took "+  Convert.ToString(stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)  + "ms to be finished.");
                Console.WriteLine("The list of all primes is now getting exported to \"primes.txt\".");
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("primes.txt");
                foreach (ulong nr in primeoutput)
                {
                   tw.WriteLine(nr);
                }
                tw.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("\nDo you want to start again?");
                string userinput = Console.ReadLine();
                string lowercaseinput = userinput.ToLower();
                if ( !(lowercaseinput.Equals("y")) )
                {
                    repeat = false;
                }
            }
        }
        public static void calcprime()
        {
            ulong k = 2;
            ulong j = i;
            ulong l = 0;
            while ( j*k <= inputnumber)
            {
                l = j*k;
                nonprimes[l] = true;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it takes around 50ms to calculate all primes until 2.000.000, previously it took over 20s to calculate until 1.000.000.
So this is a huge improvement.

ATM I can only calculate primes until barely under 2.5 million. I will work on improving the code to go further.

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution,  if you have done something in addition to the other answers then please explain in your answer so others can see how you made the code better.  Code Review allows for Self Reviews of Code.

Comment: @Kajkrow Our CoC limits how we are allowed to comment on someone's answer.  You are allowed to create a new question with this new code so that we may critique it more in-depth.  If you choose to do that, please place a link back to this thread for reference.